# Jquery ui draggable do nothing if cell is 0(collision)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

I created maze game using jquery ui draggable to run for mobile phone, so far I can make a cell with two-dimensional array,

```
[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

1 cell is 14x14 pixel.

So, if the object touches the **0** it must do nothing (it means stay at position **1**, without go to 0 first).

The problem is, jquery-ui draggable must drag first to get the object position so I can make condition for object, but I want to know first where the object will move so I can give command to move or stay.

You can check my maze game progress here, so far I can set last position if position === **1**, just change object position to last position.
https://jsfiddle.net/4xwwe5nc/1/

Thanks

**========UPDATE========**

So, I thought it could detect the area of object after drag

[image]

black dot is object, and pink area is area around the object also the containment. After that, everytime object move will create new containment around object area if **top, bottom, right, and left is not wall(0)**.
On the side sloping, may be touching the wall.

https://jsfiddle.net/dekoci/4xwwe5nc/3/

Comment: There's no JavaScript in your fiddle.

Comment: Oh, sorry just updated jsfiddle link. Thanks

Comment: I think you'd have to find a complex way to maintain `containment` for the draggable object. Since your boundries are the lines in the image, you could pass an array of bounding boxes to `containment`. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050058/bounding-snap-svg-element-to-svg-area